# Writing scala/spark info into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have a log data having data like

```
Started by timer
...
...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

For each log data ,the log status(here "Finished") and the status("SUCCESS") needs to written into MongoDB.

```
case class Logs(status:String,statusCode:String)

def main(args:Array[String]){

     val sc= new SparkContext("local[*]","MongoDB")
     val lines=sc.textFile("log1.txt")
     val pairs=lines.filter(value=>value.startsWith("Finished")).
     map(lines=>lines.split(": ")).
     map(lines=>(lines(0).toString(),lines(1).toString())).

    for(keyAndValue<-pairs){
      println("key: "+va._1+" has val: "+va._2)
    }
```

I am able to get the values correctly.

Now I would like to store them as key and value in MongoDB like ("Finished","SUCCESS"), in a particular database for a collection.

I created mongodb configuration as below:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.master("local")
.appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.test")
.config("spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred")
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.test")
.getOrCreate()
```

How do I use the class I have created to store the values?

Am I missing any additional configuration, or need to put the data differently in  the database.

I have tried to save the info into Mongo using the below snippet , but, it is indicating that 'write is not a member of RDD' .

```
pairs.foreachRDD({ rdd =>
import spark.implicits._
val matching = rdd.map({ case (status: String, statusCode: String)
=> Logs(status, statusCode) })
matching.write.mode("append").mongo()
})
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out this link : https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/write-to-mongodb/ it can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the instructions in the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/write-to-mongodb/), you must convert your RDD into a BSON document.

Also there is no need to create a `SparkSession` (from SparkSQL) and a `SparkContext` because the context is part of the session.

I built a simple example on top of your code. Since the `Logs` class must be transformed into a `Document`anyway, I omitted this step:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.bson.Document

object MongoDBTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/test.test")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name", "secondaryPreferred")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.test")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val lines = sc.textFile("log1.txt")
    val pairs = lines.filter(value => value.startsWith("Finished"))
       .map(lines => lines.split(": "))
       .map(line => new Document((line(0)), line(1)))
    for (va <- pairs) {
      println(va)
    }

    MongoSpark.save(pairs)
  }
}
```

The necessary dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.2.0"
```

A quick check in mongodb shows the result oh a minimal log file:

```
>db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a70a04737331a6da0a6ef96"), "Finished" : "SUCCESS" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a70a04737331a6da0a6ef97"), "Finished" : "FAILURE" }
```

Comment: Where do we need to add the dependencies?

Comment: I added them to the build.sbt but I guess there are several ways to handle dependencies in scala. You used SparkContext and SparkSession in your code so there should be an existing way of handling external depencies in you setup.

Comment: Is it that the Document object's first value which is line(0) contains the 'status' and the second argument of Logs which is 'statusCode' is contained in the line(1)?

Comment: Yes, for each line a new document with one key/value pair is created where the key is the status and value the statusCode

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrameWriter` is a property of a `Dataset`.

If `Logs` is a case class, like:

```
case class Logs(status: String, statusCode: String)
```

just replace

```
val matching = rdd.map({ 
  case (status: String, statusCode: String) => Logs(status, statusCode)
})
```

with

```
val matching = rdd.map({ 
  case (status: String, statusCode: String) => Logs(status, statusCode)
}).toDF
```

Comment: Converting to dataframe did not help.
 The error was shown in the line matching.write.mode("append").mongo(), w.r.t the write operation.