# Push data to mongoDB using spark from hive

Tags: sql, mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark, hive

i want to to extract data from hive using sql query convert that to a nested dataframe and push it into mongodb using spark.
Can anyone suggest a efficient way to do that .

eg:
Flat query result -->
{"columnA":123213 ,"Column3 : 23,"Column4" : null,"Column5" : "abc"}

Nested Record to be pushed to mongo -->
{
"columnA":123213,
"newcolumn" : {
"Column3 : 23,
"Column4" : null,
"Column5" : "abc"
}
}

Comment: are you seeking an answer that will write pyspark/scala code to 1. read data from hive 2. perform the transformation to create the nested data and 3. write this data to mongodb OR are you seeking an answer that will demonstrate how to perform the transformation to create the nested data ?

Comment: @ggordon  Extracting flat data from hive can be done  but It would be helpful  to know how to  perform the transformation of that data to create the nested data and then push that data to mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `map` function in spark sql to achieve the desired transformation eg

```py
df.selectExpr("ColumnA","map('Column3',Column3,'Column4',Column4,'Column5',Column5) as newcolumn")
```

or you may run the following on your spark session after creating a temp view

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_temp_view")
sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

```sql
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    map(
        "Column3",Column3,
        "Column4",Column4,
        "Column5",Column5
    ) as newcolumn
FROM 
   my_temp_view
```

Moreover, if this is the only transformation that you wish to use, you may run this query on hive also.

Additional resources:

- [Spark Writing to Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477651/writing-scala-spark-info-into-mongodb)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , this seems really helpful will let you know if this works!!

Answer (score 0):

For a nested level array for your hive dataframe we can try something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
  "newcolumn",
  F.struct(
    F.col("Column3").alias("Column3"),
    F.col("Column4").alias("Column4"),
    F.col("Column5").alias("Column5")
  )
)
```

followed by `groupBy` and `F.collect_list` to create an nested array wrapped in a single record.

we can then write this to mongo

```
df.write.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode("append").save()
```

Comment: Thanks , will try this !